# How to save claims used in a MVC site using Thinktecture IdentityModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I am working on a MVC web site with Claims Authentication and also using Thinktecture IdentityModel.

Each user has a set of CLAIMS: City, Username, Email, Roles, Birthdate.

I have 3 tables in the database: USERS, USERS_PROFILES and USERS_CLAIMS.

USERS contains the columns Username and Email;

USERS_PROFILES contains the columns City and Birthdate.

I am saving these values in these tables ... And I save the Roles in the USERS_CLAIMS table.

When I load a user I fill the ClaimsIdentity with the data from these tables.

**THE QUESTION IS:**

When I create a user should I, for example, save the email both in USERS table and in USERS_CLAIMS table?

It seems data replication but I am not sure ... Or should I save in only one of them?

What is your approach to this? And what kind of claims, beside roles, do you have that don't fit in a USERS or USERS_PROFILE table?

Thank You,

Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using `MVC` (Model View Controller), why don't you use `Models` ?

Your `ClaimsIdentity` is a model, just create a `ClaimsIdentityModel.cs` in your `Model` folder, and use it like this :

```
public class ClaimsIdentityModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Datetime Birthdate{ get; set; }        
}
```

Then, when you load your user, just fill a `ClaimsIdentityModel`. And you're done.

Comment: But on the table ... How would you store it?

Comment: Store is as you want on your table. Create a method which fill your `ClaimsIdentityModel` (with LINQ for example). It doesn't matter if datas you use to fill the model are stored in one or one hundred tables...

Answer (score 0):

As name of each table suggest, the values shall represent those only.

- Users are identified as by usernames. Email is one of the claim done by the User.
- Roles are also claims, so as City.

If you are creating profile table and adding city in profile, it shall be avoided to add it in Claims table. But you need to handle requirement of City as claim by queries Profile table and providing value as claim as needed.

ClaimsIdentity is System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity type that is used to identify the user in claim based approach.

(Making Model will be helpful in the View)